# NSNumber is not a subtype of UITextField

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield, nsnumber

I am getting an error with my code in Swift. "NSNumber is not a subtype of UITextField".
I want to see if an Int from a UITextField is equal to another Int.

Here is the code. I have put all of my code in.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var pianoSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("two_tone_nav", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSound, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var Number: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var BA50: UILabel!

@IBAction func Generate(sender: AnyObject) {

    audioPlayer.play()    

    var Generate = Int(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)
    AboveBelow50(Generate)
    Number.text = String(Generate)
    Input()
}

@IBOutlet weak var PlayerOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PlayerTwo: UITextField!

func Input() {
    let PlayerOne = self.PlayerOne.text.toInt()
    let PlayerTwo = self.PlayerTwo.text.toInt()

}

func Numberequal(Generate: Int) {
    if PlayerOne=Generate {

    }
}


func AboveBelow50(Generate: Int){
     if Generate>=50 {
         self.BA50.text = "Above 50"
      }  else {
         self.BA50.text = "Below 50"
     }    
}
}
```

Comment: Post more of your code, but the type of the entry in a UITextField is a string

Comment: So presumably one of those lines above was flagged as causing the message.  You're going to make us guess which one?

Comment: If PlayerOne=Generate is where the error is.

Comment: It says that NSNumber is not a subtype of UITextField

Comment: PlayerOne is declared as a UITextField.  Generate is declared as an Int.